# mongoskin and mongoose dependency error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to full stack javascript and have been stuck on this error for a  while now.  At first, I saw this when running "npm-install":

> npm WARN EPEERINVALID mongoskin@1.4.13 requires a peer of mongodb@~1.4
>   but none was installed.

when I do nodemon server.js, I get the following error:

> /Users.../node_modules/agenda/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:33
>   var skinClassName = 'Skin' + NativeClass.name;
>                                             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at makeSkinClass (/Users/....)

I saw that this seems to be an issue for others also:
https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/issues/153

but I'm really not sure how to proceed. Which package.json file (and where) am I supposed to be editing, and for what reason? I do not have "monk" in my npm_modules folder.

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: "mongoose": "^4.1.7" . I don't have mongoskin in my package.json, but it shows up in my node_modules.

Comment: oops my fault, I read that as mongoose. 3.0.6 version of mongodb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this fixed it! you have to npm install mongodb in the project directory and specify the version.

https://github.com/Automattic/monk/issues/91

Comment: Doesn't this downgrade you from Mongo 2 to 1? I think that would be bad.

Comment: ^ I'm concerned about the same. Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to package.json, and run 'npm install' again in your project directory.... It will reinstall/downgrade mongodb to version 1.4.4, and 'mongoskin' will install perfectly...

```
    "mongodb": "^1.4.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing older versions of MongoDb. Follow these steps:

1. npm uninsatll mongodb --save
2. npm install mongodb@1.4 --save
3. npm install monk --save

Hope this works!!